# Skew-symmetric square root of symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, skew-symmetric-matrices

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are real skew-symmetric $4 \times 4$ matrices. Hence $A^2$ and $B^2$ are symmetric matrices. Now we want to find a skew-symmetric 4×4 matrix ($C$) which satisfies

$$A^2+B^2=C^2$$

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: What do you mean by 'find'?

Comment: This is not always possible. E.g. when$$A=\pmatrix{0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&-1\\  0&0&0&0\\ 0&1&0&0},\ B=\pmatrix{0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&-2\\ 0&0&2&0},$$we have $S=A^2+B^2=\operatorname{diag}(0,-1,-4,-5)$. Since the eigenvalues of $S$ do not occur in pairs of negative real numbers, it is not a square of real skew-symmetric matrix.

Comment: The C does not need to be real.

Answer (score 0):

This is not always possible. E.g. when
$$
A=\pmatrix{0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&-1\\ 0&0&0&0\\ 0&1&0&0},
\ B=\pmatrix{0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&-2\\ 0&0&2&0},
$$
we have $S=A^2+B^2=\operatorname{diag}(0,-1,-4,-5)$. Since $S$ has nonzero eigenvalues of odd multiplicities, it is not the square of any real or complex skew-symmetric matrix.